# VBA issue with overflow

Tags: excel, vba

The following is a sample of the code I'm using to to organize large lists to to extract unique factors. The lists are comprised of multiple, smaller lists, and I'm getting issues when trying to use the xLFilterCopy Unique function as having multiple lists in the range appears to cause an error (I have functional code that works fine for lists up to 12000 data long when only using single lists, the issue comes when combining multiple lists). To solve this I created the following code:

```
Sub IfExistSetup()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
    If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
     
    Dim DoesItExist As Long
    Cells(1, 3).Value = Cells(1, 1)
    
    i = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
    Cells(i, 5).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CountIf(R1C3:R50000C2, R" & i & "C1)"
    
    DoesItExist = Cells(i, 5).Value
    
    If DoesItExist = 0 Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    
    Else
        Cells(i, 3).Value = ""
        i = i + 1
    End If
    
    Loop
    
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("C1:C2500")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

This does actually work as long as the sum of all lists is less than 2000, but I just tried running it on a compound list that is around 33000 and stopped it after 2.5 hours of it running. Note that this is the shortened version that worked fine, I did have the range longer for the section "ActiveWorkbook..." for the much longer code, however, it never got to that point. Can anyone think of a more efficient way of checking these very complicated lists?

I expected it to work as expected, the issue is after around 5000 iterations, the process slowed so much that it is not viable at all. I also cannot use any other language at the moment as my hands are tied.

Comment: One idea would be to try to do the sorts in memory instead of within the sheet. So sort the data in memory, then write out the results back out to the sheet when done.  Not sure if that would help or not though.  Another idea would be to load the data to a relational database where you can slice and dice it as needed.  Let the relational DB do the heavy lifting, then just query it for the results and populate your Excel sheets accordingly.  If you're determined to use Excel for everything, we'd need a lot more info though to determine why your code is running slow.

Comment: A screenshot of your data would be useful here.  Updating a large sheet cell-by-cell will be pretty slow.

Comment: This might be a good time to switch to Python to do this task. I have not had problems with overflows when using python. I have worked on data sets that are larger than what fits into excel without issue. It also will process faster than excel.
For the python IDE you can use Jupyter Notebooks, I like to use VS-Code made by Microsoft.

Comment: With python there is no software cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm following what you're doing with your data, but this should be faster:

```vb
Sub IfExistSetup()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dict As Object, rng As Range, arr, col As Long, rw As Long
    Dim v
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    If (ws.AutoFilterMode And ws.FilterMode) Or ws.FilterMode Then
        ws.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    ws.Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ws.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
     
    'get the range with data
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    arr = rng.Value 'read all data to array
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'collect all unique values from Cols B and C
    For rw = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'check all rows
        For col = 2 To 3
            v = arr(rw, col)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = 1 'capture unique values
        Next col
    Next rw
    
    'now check Col A values against the dictionary
    For rw = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)   'check all rows
        v = arr(rw, 1)             'Col A value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            If Not dict.Exists(v) Then 'not already in Col B/C ?
                arr(rw, 3) = v         '  put in Col C
                dict(v) = 1            '  and add to dictionary
            Else
                arr(rw, 3) = ""        'clear Col C
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
     
    rng.Value = arr 'put array back to sheet
    
    'rest as before....

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim, this worked. I was not aware you can use actual dictionaries in VBA. I have never seen one used in anything I've read. That is a very useful piece of information to know. Thank you!

Comment: Using a Dictionary to collect unique values or to map (eg) values to the row they occur on is a pretty common pattern here.  It's a useful thing to have in your toolbox.